# How to really use PhoneGap with Xcode

Tags: html, iphone, xcode, cordova, testing

I have been searching whole internet but there are tons of outdated things about this issue

I simply have PhoneGap project.
[some contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIFqd.png)

And its working flawlesly when I use the PhoneGap app for my iPhone.
Really perfectly!

So I want to really try it and test it before I maybe purchase dev acc.
But I don't know how to test it and upload the contents of PhoneGap project (which is nearly basicaly HTML and CSS website) to my iPhone.

I can do it just for my device to send a project from xcode to my iPhone.
But it "god damnned!!!" does not look like from the PhoneGap "emulator" or what so ever.
This is not right:
pubnub.com/blog/2014-10-30-converting-your-javascript-app-to-an-ios-app-w-phonegap/
and this is far beyond working
adobe.com/devnet/archive/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-xcode-for-ios.html

I can see that there is really some "Gap" and the know how is maybe "well paid" feature.
So please how can I simply test the "contents" - app from PhoneGap.
Its kind a template and then HTML website.

I see that there is lots of third party websites doing some mojo and magicaly wrap you HTML5 website, but when I wrap it as one of the tutorials above showed..its not what it supose to be.
[Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr1aI.png)

And for example the Onsen.io templates are just broken..
Is there any working tutorial how to put PhoneGap project to iPhone through Xcode? for testing?

Hint: Adobe does not allows me to make an app without signing key..so.I cannot even test it. And even if...its an APK. file and that I cannot run either..useless.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

if you gave installed phonegap/cordova locally then run this command in project folder.

```
cordova platform add ios
```

after running that cordova will create a ios project inside 
`<projectfolder>/platforms` folder. You can open it in Xcode and run it like any other Xcode project. and also deploy it to attached device to test it.